# Scalar field-particle interaction in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, classical-field-theory

Consider the interaction of a scalar field $\phi$ with a point particle $\chi \equiv \chi(\tau)$ in curved spacetime where $\tau$ is some affine parameter. The action for this system is

$$S = \underbrace{\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}~\left[-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi\right]}_{S_0[\phi]} + \underbrace{\int d\tau \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}~\dot{\chi}^{\mu}(\tau)\dot{\chi}^{\nu}(\tau)}~\lambda~\phi(\chi(\tau))}_{S_{\text{int}}[\chi,\phi]} \tag{1}$$

where $S_0$ is the usual kinetic part of the free field action and the second term represents the interaction with the coupling $\lambda$. $\dot{\chi^{\mu}}(\tau) = d\chi^{\mu}(\tau)/d\tau$.

To find the dynamical equation for the field, we vary this action with respect to the field. Doing so for the first term gives the usual result which is $\Box \phi$. However, I am not sure if I can directly vary the second term since it is not an integral of the form $\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}~\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}$. To do this, I tried to bring it to this form in the following way:

$\begin{align}
S_{\text{int}}[\chi,\phi] &= \int d\tau \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}~\dot{\chi}^{\mu}(\tau)\dot{\chi}^{\nu}(\tau)}~\lambda~\phi(\chi(\tau)) = \int \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}~d\chi^{\mu}(\tau)~d\chi^{\nu}(\tau)}\lambda~\phi(\chi(\tau)) \\ 
&= \int dt~\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\chi^{\mu}(\tau)}{dt}\frac{d\chi^{\nu}(\tau)}{dt}}\lambda~\phi(\chi(\tau)) = \int d^4x \left[\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\chi^{\mu}(\tau)}{dt}\frac{d\chi^{\nu}(\tau)}{dt}}\lambda~\phi(\chi(\tau))\right]\delta^3(x^i - \chi^i) \\ 
S_{\text{int}}[\chi,\phi] &= \int d^4x \sqrt{-g}\underbrace{\left[\frac{\delta^3(x^i - \chi^i)}{\sqrt{-g}}~\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\chi^{\mu}(\tau)}{dt}\frac{d\chi^{\nu}(\tau)}{dt}}\lambda~\phi(\chi(\tau))\right]}_{\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}} \tag{2}
\end{align}$

Now, I can vary the interaction Lagrangian to obtain,

$$\frac{\partial~\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}}{\partial \phi} = \left[\frac{\lambda~\delta^3(x^i - \chi^i)}{\sqrt{-g}}~\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\chi^{\mu}(\tau)}{dt}\frac{d\chi^{\nu}(\tau)}{dt}}\right]~. \tag{3}$$

So the equation of motion would be:

$$\Box \phi = \frac{\lambda~\delta^3(x^i - \chi^i)}{\sqrt{-g}}~\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\chi^{\mu}(\tau)}{dt}\frac{d\chi^{\nu}(\tau)}{dt}} \tag{4}$$

For a particle at rest in a background $ds^2 = a^2(-dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 +dz^2)$, if I consider $\chi^\mu = (t,0,0,0)$, then my equation must be:

$$\Box \phi = \frac{\lambda~\delta^3(x^i)}{a^3}~. \tag{5}$$
I have the following questions:

1. Is my procedure for obtaining the interaction Lagrangian in eqn (2) correct, or is there a different way varying $S_{\text{int}}$?
2. If eqn (2) is correct, then when I proceed to write down eqn (3) do I need to account for the fact that $\phi \equiv \phi(\chi)$ when I take the derivative wrt $\phi$?

Comment: *Is my procedure … correct?* [Should any check-my-work questions be made on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic)